# Intuition/ meaning of theorem about separable spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the idea behind this theorem? Is there any proof or justification for that?

*Thm:* A Hilbert space $H$ is separable if and only if it contains a countable set which is dense in $H$.

Also, it needs an explanation about the terminology "dense" here: If $\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, ... \}$ be an orthonormal basis in $H$. Then, $\text{span}\{\varphi_1,\varphi_2,...  \} $ is dense in $H$. What is the intuition/ meaning of "dense" here?

Comment: "Dense" is defined in topology as: A subset $D$ of a topological space $X$ is *dense* in $X$ if it intersects evry non-empty open set of $X$. Intuition: Any element of $X$ can nicely approximated by elements of $D$. -- Also, usually the *definition* of "separable is precisely that, i.e.: A topological space $X$ is called *separable* if it contains a countable dense subspace. So if you call that a theorem, what is the definition of separable you work with?

Comment: I would call that a definition, not a theorem; what is your definition of "separable"? (As for "dense", a set $A$ in a metric space $B$ is dense in $B$ if for any $x \in B$ there exists a sequence $x_n$ of elements of $A$ such that $x_n$ converges to $x$.)

Comment: It is a theorem in the book: Basic operator theory by Gohberg.

Comment: Sure, perhaps you could state it as a theorem if you wanted, but then you must have some equivalent definition of the term "separable" already in order for it to make sense to call it a theorem.

Comment: I don't call it theorem; it is called by the book. If you refer to the page 266 of that book, you will find it.

Comment: I don't have this book. It should not be difficult to find the original definition of "separable" given in the book.

Comment: Based on this book page 34: A Hilbert space $H$ is called separable if there exist vectors $v_1,v_2, ...$ which spans a subspace dense in $H$. I wrote definition word by word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition used here, you are given a countable set $V$ whose (algebraic) linear span is dense in $H$. (I say "algebraic" because this means we take only finite linear combinations to generate the span.) Let us assume without loss of generality that all elements of $V$ are unit.

The full linear span of $V$ is of course uncountable, because $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. But the *rational* linear span of $V$ is countable, since there is a surjection from $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{Q}^n$ to the rational linear span. (Note that here it is important that we are looking at just the algebraic linear span, because the set of *sequences* of rational numbers is *not* countable.)

I claim that the rational linear span of $V$ is still dense. Given $h \in H$, and $\varepsilon > 0$, you have $\{ c_i \}_{i=1}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{ v_i \}_{i=1}^n$ in $V$ such that $\left \| h - \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i \right \| < \varepsilon/2$. Choose $q_i$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|c_i-q_i|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2n}$, then the triangle inequality (and the assumption that the $v_i$ are unit) gives you $\left \| h -  \sum_{i=1}^n q_i v_i \right \| < \varepsilon$ as desired.

The same thing can be repeated if the base field is $\mathbb{C}$, in which case you should consider the subfield $\left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Re}(z) \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } \mathrm{Im}(z) \in \mathbb{Q} \right \}$.

Comment: Thanks @Ian. But, can you explain more about the countability of the $V$?

Comment: @Amin It is nothing special, what I'm calling $V$ is just the collection of all the vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots$ in the definition you gave in your comment.